# how to hide form control and want only value of form control elements

Tags: javascript, jsp

I only want value of field.I don't want to display this field on form.

here is my code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <% if(Dealer_cmpny_name_list.size() > 0) 
    {%>
        <label for="Dealer_Company_Name">
            Select Dealer company name:</label>
        <select name="Dealer_Company_Name" id="Dealer_Company_Name" class="form-control">
            <option>Select</option>
            <%for (int i = 0; i < Dealer_cmpny_name_list.size(); i++) 
    {%>
            <option value="<%=Dealer_cmpny_name_list.get(i)%>">
                <%=Dealer_cmpny_name_list.get(i)%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>
        <% } %>
    </div>
```

Comment: This can be done easily by using CSS. Use `style="display:none;"` on your `form-group` div..

Comment: thanks a lot!! Its working now

Comment: Great!! Posting my comment as an answer. Please accept if this helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily hide the required elements by using CSS `display` property for the `form-group` element. This can be achieved like below-

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
```